# How to print receipts on BLE Thermal Printers for a Xamarin Forms mobile app?

Tags: mobile, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, printers, receipt

I am totally new to the bluetooth world and I am current using Xamarin Forms framework to build an app which providing the feature of receipt printing on BLE printer (Currently using Mustek MK380 Thermal Printer as test device).

I am using this plugin for my app, and has been able to connect to my printer with no issue:
https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

However, I am still confused and have no idea what to do next in spite of the research I did (To understand what characteristics, services, etc are). I have played around with the plugin and also gone through the Services, Characteristics and Descriptors by log their names and values at console.

Could anyone help me or provide me some directions, or there are alternatives for my to achieve what I want, it is much appreciate if there are examples to refer.

**In short, my remarks and questions are as below:**

1. I wish to develop a Xamarin Forms app that support POS style receipt printing feature through thermal printer.
2. The printer I use is Mustek MK380 Thermal Printer supporting BLE 4.0
3. I am using https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le plugin
4. I am stucked after connecting to the printer.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to read the printers manual.  Most printers like this have their own byzantine set of control codes used to print - basically you just treat the BT connection like a serial device and write the necessary text and control codes to it

Comment: @Jason Thank you Jason, anyway the printer manufacturer did not provide any user manual but only full sets of the printer along with charger, anyway I did some digging on third party apps that is written for testing all sorts of bluetooth printers, I found one and it works perfectly, I think there might be a standard way to code and which is applicable to all types of bluetooth printers.

Comment: Can you please share with us the solution you finally found? Perhaps as a self-answered response?